# Export a small set of methods from dll's?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, dll, dllexport

My software has many sub-projects which are built into dll's, and many methods are exported as they will be used by other dependent project. We now need to expose some of the functionality in multiple dll's as API to a different project these API's are very small subset compared to all the currently exported methods on the dll's. What is the best way to provide a minimal set of API's to the outside world?

I thought, if we provide separate set of .h files with only few minimal exported public methods, then that minimal set would only be usable by outside world, correct? Is this a standard practice? Any better alternatives?

The source code is in C++, VS2010, windows platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @RemyLebeau said, only create a separate API if you intend to keep both up to date and are willing to put the extra work in to keep both synchronised.

In terms of security, it has already been mentioned that if the DLL exports the symbols then they can readily be called by other programs, so in that sense providing a subset offers no increase in security.

That means that the choice of creating a public API comes down to user convenience and need, and not technical concerns. Exposing a subset gives a strong hint to the users about which methods are meant to be used. These concerns are weighed against the cost of having to maintain an extra API.

Answer (score 2):

Exported functions are already exposed to the outside world.  Why can't you just have the offending project use the pieces it needs from each DLL?

If you really want to expose a smaller API, I would suggest creating a new DLL that depends on the other DLLs, and exposes only their functions that you want exposed.  You would still have to distribute those DLLs, but the project would not be linking to them directly, it would link to the smaller DLL instead.

Comment: Yes, the exported methods will still be exported but I thought the user who wants to consume the api would start looking at the .h file rather than using dependency walker and see all the exported symbols? What you suggested would work, is it the standard practice? any other ways to skin the cat?

Comment: The Win32 API is a HUGE collection of thousands of DLL functions, but most people use a small subset of them.  Do you expect Microsoft to expose small subsets of the API in smaller .h files and smaller DLLs?  No.  If you have a specific task, you look for the exported functions related to that task, and ignore the others.  Same thing in custom APIs.  Just because you export a lot of functions does not mean they all have to be used.

Comment: All exported methods on Win32 api's will be used by atleast someone in the world, but this is not the case here. We export tons on methods only because it is used by another project in the solution, they never will be useful to outside world.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The DLLs that implement the Win32 API export lots of functions (typically by ordinal) that aren't documented and don't appear in the public header files.  i.e. Microsoft *do* expose a subset of the API in smaller .h files.  That is exactly what Coder777 proposed (there's no mention of modifying the DLLs) and it seems very sensible.

Comment: @Coder777 Doesn't matter; if someone cares enough, they'll call GetProcAddress & reverse-engineer the parameters.  That's what happens with the Win32 DLLs.